# Getting CCTouch points when user clicks on an Item

Tags: cocoa-touch, touch, cocos2d-x

[image: Main Screen]

Here is my main screen, when user clicks anywhere on the screen I go to the CCTouchBegan method, so far good. But I want that when user clicks on the YouTube image or any other image I should be able to tell by getting their position and comparing with the CCTouch values that are passed in CCTouchBegan event. How can I do that?

How can I get the position of every element on the screen and compare it with the current touching point?

Answer (score 1):

You would get the point the user touched at and check if the point falls within the bounding box of any of those buttons

The basic idea:

```
cocos2d::CCPoint p = pTouch->getLocation();
cocos2d::CCRect rect = this->boundingBox();

if(rect.containsPoint(p)){
    return true;
}
```